# Encountering ValueError() on importing xlwings or using pip

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, valueerror, xlwings

I'm encountering the following error when attempting to import xlwings in a PyCharm project:

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=62345
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['C:\\Users\\[USERNAME]\\PycharmProjects\\Charge_Corrections_Setup', 'C:/Users/[USERNAME]/PycharmProjects/Charge_Corrections_Setup'])
PyDev console: starting.
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> import xlwings as xw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 89, in _tempfile
    os.write(fd, reader())
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 371, in read_bytes
    with self.open('rb') as strm:
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_adapters.py", line 54, in open
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .main import (
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 2754, in <module>
    from . import conversion
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .standard import (
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\standard.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..pro import Markdown
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\pro\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .embedded_code import runpython_embedded_code, dump_embedded_code
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\pro\embedded_code.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .module_permissions import verify_execute_permission
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\pro\module_permissions.py", line 22, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\certs.py", line 15, in <module>
    from certifi import where
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 170, in exec_module
    notify_module_loaded(module)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\wrapt\decorators.py", line 470, in _synchronized
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 136, in notify_module_loaded
    hook(module)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wrapt_certifi.py", line 20, in apply_patches
    certifi_win32.wincerts.CERTIFI_PEM = certifi.where()
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\certifi\core.py", line 37, in where
    _CACERT_PATH = str(_CACERT_CTX.__enter__())
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 95, in _tempfile
    os.remove(raw_path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\[USERNAME]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp_g611hdf'
import xlwings as xw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 89, in _tempfile
    os.write(fd, reader())
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 371, in read_bytes
    with self.open('rb') as strm:
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_adapters.py", line 54, in open
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .main import (
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 2754, in <module>
    from . import conversion
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .standard import (
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\standard.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..pro import Markdown
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\pro\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .embedded_code import runpython_embedded_code, dump_embedded_code
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\pro\embedded_code.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .module_permissions import verify_execute_permission
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\pro\module_permissions.py", line 22, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 42, in <module>
    DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE_PATH = certs.where()
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\venv\lib\site-packages\certifi\core.py", line 37, in where
    _CACERT_PATH = str(_CACERT_CTX.__enter__())
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 95, in _tempfile
    os.remove(raw_path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\[USERNAME]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpkn_ssllb'
```

The second section appears to be an issue with accessing the log, so I think that's OK, but the ValueError was concerning.  This is part of a series of imports including xlrd, openpyxl, xlsxwriter and others, so it's odd that only this module is throwing an error.

Once I started troubleshooting, however, I found something even odder: any usage of pip throws the same series of errors:

```
PS C:\Users\[USERNAME]\PycharmProjects\Reports> pip install seaborn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 89, in _tempfile
    os.write(fd, reader())
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 371, in read_bytes
    with self.open('rb') as strm:
  File "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_adapters.py", line 54, in open
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
```

It also throws the file access issue but I'm omitting it for space.

I'm not sure what the issue is here, or even where to look really.  We just updated our web proxy at work, but I encountered that issue yesterday and believed I had fixed it by updating the certificates, both in the environment and in the PyCharm settings.  After doing so pip and all programs were working last night before logging out, but first thing this morning here is this issue.

It's possible the proxy is the issue, but I don't even know where to start looking to diagnose that that I haven't already done, especially since the value error isn't specific.

If anyone has even an idea of where to look or what the root cause might be I'd be extremely grateful!

Comment: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.   Close everything and retry.

Comment: Thanks, but a second test immediately after restarting the computer produced the same issue.  As far as I can tell the file access issue if coming from it trying to write an error log for the first error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip broke after downlading python-certifi-win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72280762/pip-broke-after-downlading-python-certifi-win32)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone runs into this in the future, this was resolved by completely purging my PyCharm install and starting from scratch.

Best I can this was caused by installing the python-certifi-win32 package while using a fairly complex web proxy.  PyCharm already was picky about the certificates supplied by the proxy and letting python-certifi-win32 meddle with them appears to have been a step to far.

There appear to have been documented cases of similar issues in the past (see [HERE](https://gitlab.com/alelec/python-certifi-win32/-/issues/9)) but the addition of the proxy turned an annoying issue into a broken one, completely breaking PIP and not even allowing the uninstallation of the package.

As this is quite specific to my organization's settings I doubt anyone else will encounter this, but just in case, maybe this will help.