# pip broke after downlading python-certifi-win32

Tags: python, pip

I have downloaded python for the first time in a new computer(ver 3.10.4).
I have download the package `python-certifi-win32`, after someone suggested it as a solution to a SSL certificate problem in a similar question to a problem I had.
Since then, pip has completely stopped working, to the point where i can't not run `pip --version`
Every time the same error is printed, it is mostly seemingly junk(just a deep stack trace), but the file at the end is different.

start of the printed log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 89, in _tempfile
    os.write(fd, reader())
  File "C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 371, in read_bytes
    with self.open('rb') as strm:
  File "C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_adapters.py", line 54, in open
    raise ValueError()
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

last row of the printed log:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\-----\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpunox3fhw'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer in another question -
[PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: after installing python-certifi-win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72011315/permissionerror-winerror-32-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is)

basically, you should remove two files that initialize `python-certifi-win32` when running pip. the files are located in the directory:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages
```

and their names are:

```
python-certifi-win32-init.pth
distutils-precedence.pth
```

Shoutout to Richard from the mentioned post :)

Comment: The package python-certifi-win32 is a nightmare! But the above reply can disable it and bring pip and conda back to life!

Comment: Amazing! I've been banging my head against unhelpful Google results for ages today, and this answer got pip working again for me :)

Answer (score 4):

While removing the offending `.pth`-files lead to a working `pip` again for me, the functionality of the `python-certifi-win32` was lost with doing so.

Andrew Leech, the author of `python-certifi-win32`, [suggests to move on](https://gitlab.com/alelec/python-certifi-win32/-/issues/14#note_876668521) to his other project [pip-system-certs](https://gitlab.com/alelec/pip-system-certs) . Drop-in replacing the library with `pip-system-certs` ([PyPI link](https://pypi.org/project/pip-system-certs/)) solved all issues for me that resulted with upgrading to Python 3.10.