# pip install error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I'm trying to do: `pip install pandas_datareader`

I'm getting this error.

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpmyj3mha6'
```

I ran the pip install process from the Anaconda Prompt, which I ran both normally and in Administrator mode. I also uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda this morning. Everything worked totally fine yesterday and I don't know what changed overnight. Maybe there is some kind of virus checker process running, or maybe there is an issue with a firewall. Not sure. How can I troubleshoot this and get things back in business?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change two file names and then everything worked fine.

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages
```

File names:

```
python-certifi-win32-init.pth
distutils-precedence.pth
```

Found the solution here.

[pip broke after downlading python-certifi-win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72280762/pip-broke-after-downlading-python-certifi-win32)